Unknown symbol device_create (err -22)
I am writing a kernel module about SPI driver. It compiles with no errors and warnings but when I try sudo insmod my_mod.ko I get:
si446x_driver: disagrees about version of symbol device_create
si446x_driver: Unknown symbol device_create (err -22)
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'si446x_driver': Invalid argument

Here is my kernel module source code:
static int si446x_probe(struct spi_device *spi)
{
    int ret = 0;

    if (si446x_dev.major) {
        si446x_dev.devid = MKDEV(si446x_dev.major, 0);
        ret = register_chrdev_region(si446x_dev.devid, SI446X_CNT, SI446X_NAME);
    } else {
        ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&si446x_dev.devid, 0, SI446X_CNT, SI446X_NAME);
        si446x_dev.major = MAJOR(si446x_dev.devid);
        si446x_dev.minor = MINOR(si446x_dev.devid);
    }
    
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk("si446x chrdev_region err!\r\n");
        return ret;
    }
    printk("si446x major = %d,minor = %d\r\n",si446x_dev.major, si446x_dev.minor); 

    si446x_dev.cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    cdev_init(&si446x_dev.cdev, &si446x_fops);
    ret = cdev_add(&si446x_dev.cdev, si446x_dev.devid, SI446X_CNT);
    if (ret < 0)
        return ret;

    si446x_dev.class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, SI446X_NAME);
    if (IS_ERR(si446x_dev.class))
        return PTR_ERR(si446x_dev.class);

    si446x_dev.device = device_create(si446x_dev.class, NULL, si446x_dev.devid, NULL, SI446X_NAME);
    if (IS_ERR(si446x_dev.device))
        return PTR_ERR(si446x_dev.device);
    return 0;
}

and in the /sys/class/spi_master/ and /sys/bus/spi/devices/ can found my SPI device.

Have you compiled against the correct kernel headers, that exactly match what's running?  And with the same compiler as used for the kernel?  Symbol version disagreement usually indicates attempting to insert a module compiled for a different kernel.

@TobySpeight  my running kernel version is 6.1.55+gac133460088a and my module version is vermagic:       6.1.55-dirty SMP preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8. I'm not sure they're compatible.

That could well be the cause of your problem.  Unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable enough to take this further and help you find the correct headers and toolchain to build with.

You need to build a kernel module against the very kernel you are running.

@TobySpeight Thanks for your comment.Next, I will confirm whether this problem is the cause.
